# How to move a range of cells with many formulas to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet which started small and got bigger and bigger.

The left half is a tabular area of data. The right side has got a bunch of calculated cells (totals, sums, different analysis ... -  this has become rather complex...)

When I scroll to the bottom of my tabular list to add new rows I cannot see the calculated area any more - bad design...

I do not know a way to *freeze* the right half...

So I tried to copy the right half to another sheet. Now the problem:

All formulas where entered without a sheet name reference originally.

### Question

Is there a way to move a range of cells from one sheet to another sheet and keep all formulas *pointing to cells which are not moved* still reading from the original sheet (add Sheet reference to them)?

Comment: You may want to consider using the camera tool:[Use the Camera Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxUTjtFsDMk)

Comment: @Jochen approach will work but have you considered using Split?  Or New Window?

Comment: Did you try `cut and paste`?  That way whatever is there should carry over to the new sheet.

Comment: @ian0411, of course I tried :-D But the problem is, that the copied cells are pointing to cells of the new sheet. I wanted to keep them pointing to the original addresses.

Comment: @ThomasInzina The camera tool is a really cool feature! Thx! Have to dive into it ... ad "split": This is splitting horizontally only, isn't it? "New Window" with a "side-by-side" view is a good approach.

Comment: You can scroll in any direction with split

Comment: @ThomasInzina Yes, I've tried that. But the left and right side of a splitted window (let's say down left and down right) do the *vertical* move synchronously.

Comment: @ThomasInzina To get it to the point: The best solution was a vertical splitter which allows to scroll the left side without moving the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freeze Panes should work if you select the cell below the bottom left of the area you wish to freeze, and select Freeze Panes.  Split (button to the right of Freeze Panes) should work if you still need to scroll in the right section.  Another option may be to reference the cells in your new sheet and leave the formulas in the original worksheet (ex. A1 in your new sheet = `OriginalWorksheet!A1`).  Without the sheet referenced in the formula, I don't believe there is a way to move the formulas and keep the original sheet reference.

Comment: Split and Freeze might work, but the area with computed cells is almost down to the bottom of the screen - and still growing... It works, but the scrollable area with my tabular data is just a few lines high...

Comment: Your second approach is exactly what I've done now. I duplicated the sheet and replaced the tabular data with a pure reference to the same cell in the other sheet. All calculations work well and inserts are done in the other place. Then I use "new window" and "side-by-side* without synced scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correct:

You can cut the area with your formulas and paste them to the same region in your new sheet. Then copy the formulas in the new sheet and paste it back to the original area. Done.

After that you can delete rows/columns in your new sheet to get your formulas in the top right corner.

Comment: I assume they want to move the formulas to a new sheet but leave the target data in it's place... Could be wrong though as the post is rather ambiguous.

Comment: Thats what I understood too.... Try cutting, pasting and copying back as I wrote, it will do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: To add sheet name references to formula following OP request**
**Regular expression taken from [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/993314)**
**Substitute pattern referenced from [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)**

**You will need to add the reference for "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" in Tools>References**

Working example of the [RegEx used here](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99199)
*This will pick up number and letter sequences elsewhere in your code if they exist though so a bit of sanity checking may be required here.*

---

Ranges need to be the same size. I kept it very basic as you haven't provided any code to work with.

```
Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 as Range
Dim x as long, y as long, r as long, c as long
Dim RegEx As Object

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
On Error Resume Next

RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.Pattern = "\b[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}\b"

set rng1 = Workbooks("BookName").Worksheets("SheetName1").Range("A1:B2")     'target cells
set rng2 = Workbooks("BookName").Worksheets("SheetName2").Range("AA1:AB2")   'contains the formula

r = rng.rows.count
c = rng.columns.count

For x = 1 to r
 For y = 1 to c
  rng2.Cells(x, y).formula = RegEx.Replace(rng1.Cells(x, y).formula,"SheetName2$&")
 Next y
Next x

On Error GoTo 0
```

Wrote in psuedo so this is untested but should work. <s>Forces the formula to be handled as a string to make sure it isn't auto-updated but if it errors just remove the `"" &` from within the loop.</s>

Comment: But this would - similar to a pure copy&paste - move the formulas just *as-is*? I need to change them in the way, that all formulas (and part of formulas!) pointing to address *outside* of the copied range get a sheet name addes to their address. I assume, this is not possible, at least not in an affordable approach. Thx

Comment: @Shnugo Please take a look and see if the edited answer fits the scenario, I just added a little RegEx to include the sheet name

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't scroll up and see the accepted answer ^^